# How to parse htmlentities with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to set the text of a button :

```
<input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm " id="sauver" type="submit" />
...
$("#sauver").prop("value","D&eacute;valider");
```

At runtime the html code **`&eacute;`** is not converted to **`é`** ! So how to fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need it, you can create a detached node:

```js
jQuery(function($){
  $dummy = $("<div />").html("D&eacute;valider");
  $("#sauver").prop("value", $dummy.text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm " id="sauver" type="submit" />
```

Of course, there's absolutely no need for such HTML entities unless your source code is written in plain 7-bit US-ASCII. The attribute itself does not expect or accept HTML anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can decode your html string like this. Wrap html element and get decoded string.

```js
function decodeEntities(encodedString) {
    var textArea = document.createElement('textarea');
    textArea.innerHTML = encodedString;
    return textArea.value;
}

var Result = decodeEntities('D&eacute;valider'); 
$("#sauver").prop("value",Result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm " id="sauver" type="submit" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert html to text by inserting it into an element as html then retrieving as text.

```js
var txt = $('<span>').html("D&eacute;valider").text()

$("#sauver").prop("value",txt);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm " id="sauver" type="submit"  />
```

Answer (score 2):

you can decode your html entities like this .

```
var text = $("<span />").html("D&eacute;valider");
$("#sauver").attr("value",text.text());
```

you can also write a common method for that:

```
function decode_entities(text) {
    var t =  $("<span />").html(text);
    return t.text();
}

$("#sauver").attr("value",decode_entities("D&eacute;valider"));
```

Comment: Thankyou for suggession...@TobySpeight..I am correcting my answer method

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `<button>` html element. And then, just access to his html:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="sauver" type="submit"></button>

$("#sauver").html('D&eacute;valider');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can put it in a "virtual" element and grab it from there encoded:

```
var myVal = "&eacute;";
var convertedVal = $('<san/>').html(myVal).text();
$("#sauver").prop("value",convertedVal);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple short trick would be to use a temporary element on which you assign the message containing the HTML entity using `.html()` and then extract the text using `.text()`.

```js
var htmlEntity = $("<div>").html("D&eacute;valider").text();

$("#sauver").prop("value",htmlEntity);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm " id="sauver" type="submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="sauver" type="submit"></button>
....
$("#sauver").html("D&eacute;valider"); //Or whatever value you want here
```

Should do the trick